# How come is `thread_rng` defined in the Chapter 7.4 snippet

Tags: rust, module

I’m currently reading [chapter 7.4](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html) of the rust book about `use` and I don’t understand the snippet:

```
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..=100);
}
```

I don't understand why the `use rand::Rng` (getting the struct `Rng` into scope) but the `rand::thread_rng()` usage. I'm guessing that the thread_rng is a Rng builder but this looks odd to me, unexplicit.

I would have expected `use rand` only since `thread_rng` is in the `rand` namespace. And I don't understand how it can work since the `rand` itself is not into scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use rand;` would be useless, as `rand` is already in scope.

However, [`rand::Rng` is a trait](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/trait.Rng.html). And one of its method is `gen_range()`. You can only call trait methods if the trait is in scope. If you remove this `use`, you get an error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `gen_range` found for struct `ThreadRng` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:2:44
    |
2   |     let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..=100);
    |                                            ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `ThreadRng`
    |
   ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rand-0.8.5/src/rng.rs:129:8
    |
129 |     fn gen_range<T, R>(&mut self, range: R) -> T
    |        --------- the method is available for `ThreadRng` here
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
    |
1   | use rand::Rng;
    |
```

Comment: so when you use a function that returns a given struct (here `ThreadRng`) implementing a given trait (here `Rng`) then you need to explicitly brings this trait into scope? how can you know this before getting a compilation error?

Comment: @ClementWalter This is not related to a function returning a struct, any time you have an instance of a struct implementing a trait and you want to call the trait's method you need to import it (or use fully-qualified syntax). How do you know it? Well, either you know it's from the trait, or the compiler will tell you.

Comment: I'd bet that in this case the fully qualified syntax may be neater imho https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name

Answer (score 1):

When you add a dependency to your `Cargo.toml`, such as `rand = *`. It **automatically** enters the global scope inside your crate. This is why you can use it as `rand::thread_rng()`.

However, this is only true of rust `2018`. Before that you needed a `extern crate rand;` statement, which would bring rand into scope. Nowadays, it just enters global scope.